# I recently updated my MacBook and since then I am facing this problem in my viscode where the first 4 lines are frozen

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I recently updated my MacBook and since then I have been facing this problem in my viscose where the first 4 lines are frozen from line number 2 to line no 45 and when I scroll the freezer for line are still stuck there only 4 lines get updated.

Here is the screenshot attached below

How can I unfreeze these row issues in MacBook?

Comment: "problem in my viscose" - do you mean VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can help you,

view->appearance->sticky scroll to uncheck

[image]

or you can right_click on freeze area->sticky scroll to uncheck

[image]